# Record is updated successfully with "force:recordData" but in response getting Error status code as 'INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS'

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-data-service, force-recorddata

In my Lightning component, I am using Force:recordData to update the record It is getting updated but throwing error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Test.cmp code

```html
<force:recordData aura:id="recordHandler"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      targetFields="{!v.caseRecord}"
                      fields="Id,
                              Comments,
                              OwnerId,
                              CaseNumber,
                              Status,
                              Origin,                        
                              "
                      mode="EDIT"        
                      recordUpdated="{!c.onInit}"
                      targetError="{!v.loadError}"
                      />
```

TestController.js

```javascript
component.find("recordHandler").saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(saveResult) {   
    if(saveResult){
         if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {    
             console.log('success');
         }


else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") { 
 if(saveResult.error[0]){
     console.log('error',saveResult.error[0]);
       console.log('error message',saveResult.error[0].message);
      }
   }         
}
```

On inspecting console.log('error message',saveResult.error[0].message) printing

> "You do not have the required level of access to perform the requested operation. Please contact the record owner or your administrator if access is required"

Answer (score 0):

The error which is coming in console.log  seems to be some access issue. Below solution might help you.

Lightning Data Service applies sharing and FLS rules. Verify that the user has access to the specified entity, record and fields which you are trying to update. If at object level user have access then please check whether field level access of all those fields which you are trying to update is available for that user.

Check out this [Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_save_record.htm) as well it might be a good help.